# ndk-gdb equivalent using gradle and cmake

Tags: android, c++, debugging, android-ndk, gdb

I am developing on an android native C++ project. Previously we used ndk r15, and would call ndk-build to build the app.

I could then call ndk-gdb to automatically attach an instance of gdb to the running app, on an adb connected device.

Now we have migrated to using gradle and cmake to build the application. ndk-gdb is no longer working with the new build system.

When building with gradle and cmake, is there a provided script in the ndk to easily attach a command line instance of a debugger to your application over adb?

Comment: I answered from your another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53735039/8034839