# Lldb debugging using lldb-server on android?

Tags: android, linux, debugging, lldb

I currently dont have a pc. I have two rooted devices `Arm64` host device with Debian rootfs and the device to be debugged which contains the lldb-server binary `armv7`. I am trying to remote debug my android device using lldb. I pulled the `lldb-server` binary from àndroid ndk24 and put it in `/data/local/tmp`. Installed `Debian` `Sid` on `Another term` and `apt` installed `lldb`.

I then wifi hotspoted the client device(one with `lldb-server`) using the host with the linux rootfs.

The commands i ran on server device

```
./data/local/tmp/lldb-server platform --listen "*:2000"  --server
```

Checked using `netstat` and the lldb-server had bound to all addresses(`0.0.0.0:2000`)

On host(client `lldb`) device in `debian sid` terminal i ran:

```
apt install lldb
lldb
platform select remote-android
platform connect connect://192.168.201.132:2000
```

Then i get `error failed connect port`.

However, using `Gdb` and `gdbserver` everything worked perfectly. I have tried installing `lldb` on `debian buster` but same result and even ran the `lldb-server` binary on the host(device with `debian sid`) but same result. Right now im stuck here. How do I solve this?

Help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Just confirming that you are/are not using `adb` as in :https://stackoverflow.com/a/64997332/295004

Comment: Yes you are right im not using adb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know why, but `lldb-server` platform command is broken(mabe in my case) and should have used `lldb-server gdbserver` like this:

On `lldb-server gdbserver` command, the stub doesnt allow connections from other ips except the one it is bound to so do this:

```
iptables -I INPUT -t nat -p tcp -d 192.168.43.1 --dport 2000 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.43.1:50000
./data/local/tmp/lldb-server g 192.168.43.1:2000
```

On `lldb` client do

```
gdb-remote 192.168.43.1:2000
```

Then do normal remote debugging.