# Compile native app for aosp with debug_info in Android.bp

Tags: android, clang, lldb, android-soong

I wanna to debug an native app with lldb but the executable is not created with debug_info.

My Android.bp:

```
cc_binary {
        name: "native_algtest",
        vendor: true,
        srcs: [ 
                "algorithms/algorithms.cpp",
                "timer/timer.cpp",
                "bench_test_native/native_test.cpp", 
        ],
        cflags: [ "-fexceptions",
                "-Wreturn-type",
                "-fstandalone-debug", ],      
        arch: {
                arm64: {
                        strip: {
                                all: true,
                                keep_symbols_and_debug_frame: true,
                                keep_symbols_list: ["symbol"],
                        },
                },
        },
}
```

The result is:

```
native_algtest: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /system/bin/linker64, BuildID[md5/uuid]=058e18cc89a03fd9e065b079aff26323, not stripped
```

At first I tried "-g" instead of "-fstandalone-debug" but it had the same result.

PS: I am executing the step-by-step from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53733781/how-do-i-use-lldb-to-debug-c-code-on-android-on-command-line) but I cannot do the step 7

Target setup:

```
$ adb shell  
# lldb-server platform --listen "*:10086" --server
```

Host lldb:

```
(lldb) platform select remote-android
  Platform: remote-android
 Connected: no

(lldb) platform connect connect://localhost:10086
  Platform: remote-android
    Triple: aarch64-unknown-linux-android
OS Version: 33 (5.15.92-v8+)
    Kernel: #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Feb 28 08:59:35 UTC 2023
  Hostname: localhost
 Connected: yes
WorkingDir: /

(lldb) file /vendor/bin/native_algtest
error: '/vendor/bin/native_algtest' doesn't contain any 'remote-gdb-server' platform architectures: aarch64, arm
```

**UPDATE:**

I found the binary with the debug_info in bellow path:

> out/target/product/rpi4/symbols/vendor/bin/native_algtest

```
native_algtest: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /system/bin/linker64, BuildID[md5/uuid]=ab107c9b82e031821b405d746c91032a, with debug_info, not stripped
```

But when I push it to the target it loses the debug_info property

```
$ file out/target/product/rpi4/symbols/vendor/bin/native_algtest
out/target/product/rpi4/symbols/vendor/bin/native_algtest: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /system/bin/linker64, BuildID[md5/uuid]=ab107c9b82e031821b405d746c91032a, with debug_info, not stripped

$ adb push out/target/product/rpi4/symbols/vendor/bin/native_algtest /vendor/bin
out/target/product/rpi4/symbols/vendor/bin/native_algtest: 1 file pushed, 0 skipped. 48.2 MB/s (363640 bytes in 0.007s)

$ adb shell file vendor/bin/native_algtest
vendor/bin/native_algtest: ELF shared object, 64-bit LSB arm64, dynamic (/system/bin/linker64), for Android 33, BuildID=ab107c9b82e031821b405d746c91032a, not stripped
```

With this, there are some warnings but the no error anymore and lldb now is working without symbols

```
(lldb) file /vendor/bin/native_algtest
warning: (aarch64) /home/alisonv/.lldb/module_cache/remote-android/.cache/81BE9F9F-C3EB-E436-BEA9-954BAC713C94/libc++.so No LZMA support found for reading .gnu_debugdata section
warning: (aarch64) /home/alisonv/.lldb/module_cache/remote-android/.cache/7D87B110-4B41-B71F-169B-1597F383F8DE/libm.so No LZMA support found for reading .gnu_debugdata section
warning: (aarch64) /home/alisonv/.lldb/module_cache/remote-android/.cache/89ABE049-041F-B6B3-C44B-0CA03C962304/libdl.so No LZMA support found for reading .gnu_debugdata section
warning: (aarch64) /home/alisonv/.lldb/module_cache/remote-android/.cache/2D9F3F22-7934-C75F-6CB7-8C1B8B81EE8F/ld-android.so No LZMA support found for reading .gnu_debugdata section
Current executable set to '/vendor/bin/native_algtest' (aarch64).
(lldb) b 13
Breakpoint 1: where = native_algtest`main + 368 at native_test.cpp:13:29, address = 0x00000000000059f0
```