android studio how to debug aosp native system_process
I'm learn aosp6.0.0_r1 , now i want to lean binder , I want to debug android_util_binder.cpp .
but I don't know how to start the debug .
On my understand , Android studio are enable debug aosp native process . like him ask : "Unable to find project context to attach debugger for xxx" on Android Studio Iguana
But i don't know how to operate stap by stap .

on Debian . Use Android Studio , I can't attach to system_process ,
android studio version is 2023.1.1 Patch 2
On MacOs . Use Android Studio , I can can attach to system_process , but native breakpoint not stop . the android studio version is 2023.3.1
I have add the symbols


Oh the other hand ,  I have tried adbclient.sh ;
I always got the err info , and can't really stop on my breakpoint:
i want to stop at android_os_BinderInternal_getContextObject but i can't .
__epoll_pwait () at bionic/libc/arch-arm/syscalls/__epoll_pwait.S:16
16          ldmfd   sp!, {r4, r5, r6, r7}
Breakpoint 1 at 0xb4cce428: file art/runtime/fault_handler.cc, line 75.
ART debugging mode is enabled.
If you are debugging a native only process, you need to
re-enable normal SIGSEGV handling using this command:
  handle SIGSEGV print stop
(gdb) break android_os_BinderInternal_getContextObject
Breakpoint 2 at 0xb6ed1508: file frameworks/base/core/jni/android_util_Binder.cpp, line 900.
(gdb) info breakpoints
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address    What
1       breakpoint     keep y   0xb4cce428 in art::art_sigsegv_fault() at art/runtime/fault_handler.cc:75
        silent
        printf "Caught SIGSEGV in user program\n"
2       breakpoint     keep y   0xb6ed1508 in android_os_BinderInternal_getContextObject(JNIEnv*, jobject) at frameworks/base/core/jni/android_util_Binder.cpp:900
(gdb) continue
Continuing.
[New Thread 1141]
[New Thread 299]
[New Thread 1142]

Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
[Switching to Thread 299]
0xb4b190fe in RevokeAllThreadLocalBuffers (this=0xb4e71600) at art/runtime/gc/collector/mark_sweep.cc:1393
1393        GetHeap()->AssertAllBumpPointerSpaceThreadLocalBuffersAreRevoked();
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
notify_gdb_of_libraries () at bionic/linker/linker.cpp:216
216       _r_debug.r_state = r_debug::RT_CONSISTENT;
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Child terminated with signal = 0x4 (SIGILL)

Program terminated with signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
The program no longer exists.
(gdb) GDBserver exiting

If you know how to debug aosp native process , please help me .

AndroidStudio is fine .
gdbclient is ok .

thank you every one .
===================
2024-05-15 20:09:36
I don't success debug AOSP native code (system_process) .
then i got one nexus 5 device and flash the aosp images to it .
retry gdb debug  , success .

Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction. info never show
look's good
emm , $2 = <optimized out> is another question  , no answer .


08:00:37 tom@ZY-C02FM2YMMD6P android-6.0.0_r1 → gdbclient system_server 9999
Resolved pid for system_server is 26742
Starting gdbserver...
. adb forward for port=9999...
. starting gdbserver to attach to pid=26742...
[1] 88417
. give it couple of seconds to start...
Attached; pid = 26742
Listening on port 9999
. done
平台名: darwin
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.7
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-apple-darwin --target=arm-linux-android".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/aosp_hammerhead-eng/build_out/target/product/hammerhead/symbols/system/bin/app_process32...done.
Remote debugging from host 127.0.0.1
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for 20 libraries, e.g. /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat.
Use the "info sharedlibrary" command to see the complete listing.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
__epoll_pwait () at bionic/libc/arch-arm/syscalls/__epoll_pwait.S:16
16      ldmfd   sp!, {r4, r5, r6, r7}
(gdb) info breakpoints
No breakpoints or watchpoints.
(gdb)

(gdb) break ProcessState.cpp:170
Breakpoint 1 at 0xb6f07942: file frameworks/native/libs/binder/ProcessState.cpp, line 170.
(gdb) break ProcessState.cpp:178
Breakpoint 2 at 0xb6f07976: file frameworks/native/libs/binder/ProcessState.cpp, line 178.
(gdb) continue
Continuing.
[New Thread 26763]
[Switching to Thread 26763]

Breakpoint 1, android::ProcessState::lookupHandleLocked (this=this@entry=0xb0706440, handle=handle@entry=6) at frameworks/native/libs/binder/ProcessState.cpp:171
171           "N=[%d] , handle=[%d]", N, handle);
(gdb) print handle
$1 = 6
(gdb) print N
$2 = <optimized out>
(gdb) info breakpoints
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address    What
1       breakpoint     keep y   0xb6f07942 in android::ProcessState::lookupHandleLocked(int) at frameworks/native/libs/binder/ProcessState.cpp:170
    breakpoint already hit 1 time
2       breakpoint     keep y   0xb6f07976 in android::ProcessState::lookupHandleLocked(int) at frameworks/native/libs/binder/ProcessState.cpp:178
(gdb)


Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/64997332/7707781 is the answer , now i don't select whick lldb-server file on ndk subdir . if i don't i will try one by one
